# Proving equivalence relation and classes

Tags: relations

I was wondering how I could prove

aRb if and only if 5 | (a + 4b) , on the set of all integers

I'm used to proving for sets of numbers so I have no idea how to start out for this... Equivalence relation I know means reflexive, symmetric and transitive, but how can I prove it for that relation?

And also how can I show the equivalence classes of R (the above relation)?

Comment: Note that $5 \mid a+4b$ **iff** $5 \mid a-b$. Hence $a R b$ **iff** $f(a) = f(b)$, where $f(n) = n \mod 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\r{\mathrel{\rm R}}$Remember that in proof problems, correct logic and clear setting out are both vital.

*Reflexive*.  For any integer $a$ we have $5\mid 5a$ by definition of divisibility.  This can be written as
$$5\mid (a+4a)\ ,$$
and therefore $a\r a$.  Thus $\r$ is reflexive.

*Symmetric*.  Let $a,b$ be integers and suppose that $a\r b$.  By definition, this means that
$$5\mid(a+4b)\ .$$
But clearly $5\mid5(a+b)$, and so by well-known properties of divisibility,
$$5\mid(5(a+b)-(a+4b))\ ,$$
that is,
$$5\mid(b+4a)\ .$$
Thus $b\r a$.  We have proved that if $a\r b$ then $b\r a$; so $\r$ is symmetric.

*Transitive*.  The layout of the proof will be similar to the proof that $\r$ is symmetric (though of course the content will be different).  Please try it for yourself.

*Equivalence classes*.  For example, the equivalence class of $1$ is by definition the set of all $a$ such that $a\r1$; that is, the set of all $a$ such that $5\mid(a+4)$.  This divisibility statement can be written $a+4=5k$, or $a=5k-4$.  So the equivalence class of $1$ is
$$[1]=\{5k-4:k\in{\Bbb Z}\}=\{\ldots,-9,-4,1,6,11,16,\ldots\}\ .$$
If you work out the rest for yourself I think you will soon realise that this relation is in fact just *congruence modulo $5$*, written in a slightly disguised way.

Good luck!

Comment: "But clearly 5∣5(a+b)" I don't understand your reasoning for this part! (In the symmetric explanation)

Comment: The symbol $\mid$ means "is a factor of".

Comment: Youre using 1 as an example here, but since it's b we're talking about, it would be [b] = {5k-4b : k ∈ ℤ} ?

Comment: And therefore {..., 5-4b, 10 - 4b, 15 - 4b,...}?